# Unable to successfully run packaged version of functional options pattern (FOP) that uses Go generics and embedded interfaces

Tags: go, generics, idioms

In an effort to learn idiomatic Go, I am trying to write a reusable package (say`base` for purposes of this question). This package provides a `Base` interface, with minimally required functions and a `BaseStruct` to implement those functions. `Base` is to be embedded in other application-domain specific packages, say **comp**osite packages.

```
type Base interface {
    defaultCfg()
    setID(string)
    setEnqSize(int)
}

type BaseStruct struct {
    id      string
    enqSize int
}

func New[T Base](t T, opts ...func(T)) T {
// Code is provided in playground below.
}

type Comp interface {
    Base
    setConn(string)
}

type CompStruct struct {
    Base
    conn string
}
// Other code in playground.
```

Critical requirements for me:

- Create new instances of composite structs using some constructional pattern like builder or functional options pattern. I was able to get FOP working with the `New` function.
- Provide a 'default' set of values using `defaultCfg` for the base and each composite, which can be overridden during the process of construction of the composite structures.
- Disallow modification of the structs' fields directly. Modifications occur either through private setters for construction, and public messages for state changes.

I'm basically writing an actor model framework that uses an actor-tree based communication pattern. The framework mostly works (message passing, etc.) barring this ability to reliably construct the actors prior to their launch.

Being a novice at Go, I have hit a brick wall trying to understand and resolve run-time panic when packaging my functions.

I wrote up some minimal code to isolate the issue. The playgrounds below do not have any actor model code, just renamed units to demonstrate my issue. The working code for instantiation is in [this playground](https://go.dev/play/p/dwuckFFJzPl?v=goprev). The output of working code:

```
defBase: {id:"DefaultID",   enqSize:1}
idBase: {id:"Non-Def-ID",   enqSize:1}
myBase: {id:"Non-Def-ID",   enqSize:4}

defComp: {Base:{id:"DefaultID", enqSize:1}, conn:"DefaultConn"}
idComp: {Base:{id:"Non-Def-ID", enqSize:1}, conn:"DefaultConn"}
myComp: {Base:{id:"Non-Def-ID", enqSize:4}, conn:"Non-Def-Conn"}

Program exited.
```

However, when I re-packaged the code as in [this non-working playground](https://go.dev/play/p/oxB889ccEdm?v=goprev), the code runs to a panic when constructing even the default composite structure. Output (the first two lines are just a check for me.):

```
Type of BaseStruct is: base.BaseStruct
Type of CompStruct is: comp.CompStruct

defBase: {id:"DefaultID",   enqSize:1}
idBase: {id:"Non-Def-ID",   enqSize:1}
myBase: {id:"Non-Def-ID",   enqSize:4}

panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x18 pc=0x482f44]

goroutine 1 [running]:
play.ground/comp.(*CompStruct).play.ground/base.defaultCfg(0x1?)
    <autogenerated>:1 +0x24
play.ground/base.withDefault[...].func1()
    /tmp/sandbox109723629/base/base.go:16 +0x2f
play.ground/base.New[...]({0x4bafe0?, 0xc00006e060}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x1})
    /tmp/sandbox109723629/base/base.go:6 +0x47
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox109723629/prog.go:34 +0x379

Program exited.
```

I have a workaround, as taken from [Dave Cheney](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/10/17/functional-options-for-friendly-apis), where the `New` function gets repeated in the comp package as well. Definition is something like:

```
func NewComp(options ...func(Comp)) Comp {
    var e Comp = &CompStruct{
        Base: base.NewBase(),
        conn: "DefaultConn",
    }

    for _, option := range options {
        option(e.(Comp))
    }
    return e.(Comp)
}
```

However, I would like to avoid creating variants of New for each composite package that is dependent on Base (or another composite). Referring to the complete code in either playground, I would also like to avoid specifying the instance of a generic for each `WithXxx` option; and instead have it use the instance specified for the `New` function. Is that possible?

Any pointers for a fix and any suggestions for writing code or this post better are gladly welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The program panics because the CompStruct.Base field is `nil`. Initialize the field by changing all uses of `new(comp.CompStruct)` with `&comp.CompStruct{Base: &base.BaseStruct{}}`.

Comment: Thank you. That did fix the panics. Curiously though, the `conn` field in `CompStruct` remained blank, implying that the `defaultCfg` of this struct was not invoked. I confirmed this by putting in a print message within both the defaultCfg methods.Also, upon reverting to my original `new(comp.CompStruct)`, but this time making `defaultCfg` exportable, i.e. `DefaultCfg`, I saw comp's function properly invoked; thereby initializing all fields of `CompStruct`.

Comment: Oops, hit some time and character limits there. Just wanted to add that I am tempted to leave `DefaultCfg` exportable so that each composite has control over what it wants its defaults to be upon instantiation.